# XML/XSD White spaces are required between publicId and systemId

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation, xsd, doctrine

I've got a PHP project in Eclipse with a lot of XML files.  Right now, all my XML files are failing validation, with the following error message:

```
White spaces are required between publicId and systemId
```

I've searched around, and publicId and systemId seem to be related to XML files that start with DOCTYPE.  Mine don't.  Another [SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8791730/827480) indicated to add the XSD to the XML catalog in Eclipse, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

One sample XML is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                          http://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="Doctrine\Tests\Models\CMS\CmsAddress" table="cms_users">

        <named-native-queries>
            <named-native-query name="find-all" result-set-mapping="mapping-find-all">
                <query>SELECT id, country, city FROM cms_addresses</query>
            </named-native-query>

            <named-native-query name="find-by-id" result-class="CmsAddress">
                <query>SELECT * FROM cms_addresses WHERE id = ?</query>
            </named-native-query>

            <named-native-query name="count" result-set-mapping="mapping-count">
                <query>SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM cms_addresses</query>
            </named-native-query>
        </named-native-queries>

        <sql-result-set-mappings>
            <sql-result-set-mapping name="mapping-find-all">
                <entity-result entity-class="CmsAddress">
                    <field-result name="id" column="id"/>
                    <field-result name="city" column="city"/>
                    <field-result name="country" column="country"/>
                </entity-result>
            </sql-result-set-mapping>

            <sql-result-set-mapping name="mapping-without-fields">
                <entity-result entity-class="CmsAddress"/>
            </sql-result-set-mapping>

            <sql-result-set-mapping name="mapping-count">
                <column-result name="count"/>
            </sql-result-set-mapping>
        </sql-result-set-mappings>

        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>

        <field name="country" column="country" type="string" length="50"/>
        <field name="city" column="city" type="string" length="50"/>
        <field name="zip" column="zip" type="string" length="50"/>

        <one-to-one field="user" target-entity="CmsUser" inversed-by="address">
            <join-column referenced-column-name="id" />
        </one-to-one>

    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

I'm a bit stumped at what to try next.  I can disable XML validation, but I hate doing things like that to resolve errors in Eclipse.  If it makes any difference, I'm using Eclipse 3.7 with PDT.  The XML files that fail are all part of libraries so I presume it must be an Eclipse configuration detail that had to be modified/rectified to resolve the issue, but I have no idea what.

Any suggestions what I can try to have my XML files validate?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong here, but it's nothing to do with the XML file that you've shown us.

Comment: Agreed.  Like I said, I am fairly convinced that it is an Eclipse configuration issue, but I have no idea what.  I am showing the XML file b/c without it, the first question (rightly so) would be the XML file looks like.  Given that these are vendor produced XML files (and several of them), I am fairly confident that the XML files are all valid.

Comment: Note that this is not a validity issue but a well-formedness issue.  In your shoes I'd see if I could identify every XML document the system might conceivably touch on its way from a request to validate a document to the error message you are seeing.  The document being validated (if the example you show is typical, the problem is not here), the schema documents defining the schema (ditto), the configuration files for Eclipse and the validation module in Eclipse, ...

Answer (score 16):

Basically, the order should be like this - property and then followed by property.xsd

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks !!

Comment: there are many similar questions..but this answer solved my issue. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a blank space " " after each URL in the  **xsi:schemaLocation** property except the last one.

xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping**<1 blank space>**http://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">