# Error loading XML schema with Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, dtd

I'm trying to parse an using [this schema](http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_schema_1_4), but I get the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_schema_1_4.xsd; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 50; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
    ...
```

Here's the relevant section of my code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

dbFactory.setValidating(true);

SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
URL schemaURL = new URL("http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_schema_1_4.xsd");
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(schemaURL); //Line causing error
dbFactory.setSchema(schema);

DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file);

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200291/xml-xsd-white-spaces-are-required-between-publicid-and-systemid) says that there should be spaces between all of the `xsi:schemaLocation`s, but there are already spaces between them. Some of the comments hint that it may be an issue with Eclipse, which is definitely a possibility.

[This question](http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_schema_1_4) says that it's a problem with the doctype declaration, but I don't know where a the comparable section of code is in my document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message comes when you seek to make a new schema object from the document whose URI is http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_schema_1_4.xsd.

There seems to be a good chance that the data the error message is complaining about is the data retrieved from that URI.  Have you tried dereferencing the URI?  What did you get?

What I got is a 404 accompanied by an HTML error page which begins:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This is not a legal XML document type declaration, and thus cannot possibly be the beginning of a legal XSD schema document.  The error message isn't providing a very good diagnosis of the problem (it suggests that the input does have a public identifier and a system identifier, but they lack a separating whitespace, when the basic problem is that neither is present at all), but the fix is unrelated to the details of the error message.  The fix is to find the correct URI for the schema document you want to load:  `http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_schema_1_4` not `http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_schema_1_4.xsd`.

Comment: I'm not sure if its working. I'm getting a different parse error on `docBuilder.parse(file)`. If this is unrelated, I'll gladly accept your answer and create another question.